# Cannot read from Java Socket on Mac

Tags: java, macos, sockets

I am teaching network communication in Java, I have a very simple client and server as a demo, using Sockets and ServerSockets. The application works as expected under Windows and Linux. All students are using Java 8 (this is a JavaFX application).

A couple of students have Macs. On the Mac, the *client* hangs when it tries to read from the socket. This is true even if the readline() method is replaced with the single-character read() method.

The answer from the server is a simple text: an HTTP 200 status, followed by sending back the client's original request. All lines are terminated with "\n". Client and server both running on the student's Mac, using port 8080 (or higher - makes no difference). Oddly, the server has no trouble reading from its socket, even though the code is the same.

Here is the relevant code in the client:

```
    StringBuffer urlContent = new StringBuffer();

    // Set up the socket
    s = new Socket(ipAddress, port);

    // Send our request, using the HTTP 1.0 protocol
    out = new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream());
    out.write("GET / HTTP/1.0\n");
    out.write("User-Agent: Browser0\n");
    out.write("Host: " + ipAddress + ":" + port + "\n");
    out.write("Accept: text/html, */*\n\n");
    out.flush();

    // Set up the reader classes
    InputStream in1 = s.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader in2 = new InputStreamReader(in1);
    inReader = new BufferedReader(in2);

    while ((lineIn = inReader.readLine()) != null) {  // Macs hang here
        urlContent.append(lineIn + "\n");
    }
```

Is there something special about using Java sockets on Macs?

Comment: The host field has to contain a domain name and not an IP address. HTTP is `\r\n` based. Read the spec before you reinvent the wheel.

Comment: The fact that this is transmitting an HTTP request is irrelevant; as far as the sockets problem is concerned, this is simply text. That said, I suppose that the line endings could be the problem.

Comment: and now you have probably found the issue yourself.

Comment: Apparently system specific: While the problem affected all students with Macs in that class, attempts to replicate the problem outside of class have failed, i.e., the demo works as expected. Hence, the problem is presumably dependent on the local configuration.